# Spring Data JPA, Hibernate and EXASOL database

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, exasolution

I'm currently facing the problem to migrate an existing application using Spring Data JPA and Hibernate from an Oracle Database to EXASOL. This should in general not be a big problem but it seems like that it is not possible use Hibernate in combination with EXASOL.

My current application.properties file:

```
#db config
db.driver=com.exasol.jdbc.EXADriver
db.url=jdbc:exa:192.168.1.11..17:8563
db.username=foobar
db.password=foobar

#hibernate config
hibernate.dialect=???
hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto=validate
hibernate.ejb.naming_strategy=org.hibernate.cfg.ImprovedNamingStrategy
hibernate.show_sql=true
hibernate.format_sql=true
```

The question is which hibernate.dialect to use?

Comment: To shorten it, the combination of Hibernate and EXASOL is not working. Plain JDBC seems to be the best way to work with EXASOL and Java.

Comment: does anything has changed?

Comment: Yes @quento, please check my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible currently to use Hibernate in combination with EXASOL. Here is the repository for the [Exasol Hibernate Dialect](https://github.com/EXASOL/hibernate-exasol) from their github page.

Comment: Disclaimer: 
Please note that this is an open source project which is not officially supported by EXASOL. We will try to help you as much as possible, but can't guarantee anything since this is not an official EXASOL product.

Answer (score 0):

EXASOL does have a hibernate dialect - please contact your support representative or post a request to the [EXASOL community](https://www.exasol.com/portal/questions) for more details